# Busca com explode e url amigavel (problema)

Tags: php, javascript, url, algoritmo-de-busca

Estou com um problema. 
Estava utilizando um sistema de busca com multipulas variáveis sem url amigavel. E funcionava normalmente. Colocava varias palavras chaves e o mesmo buscava no banco de dados sem nenhum problema através do EXPLODE.

Só que agora, coloquei URL amigável e não está funcionando. O que poderia ser? 
**Detalhe: Se eu colocar apenas um palavra, vai funcionar normalmente.** Agora se eu colocar duas palavras não aparece os resultados.

Formulário de busca

```
    <div class="default-form-area">
            <form id="formBuscar" class="default-form" action="" method="GET">
                <div class="row clearfix">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" name="search" id="search"  class="form-control" value="<?php if(isset($_GET["search"])) echo $_GET["search"]; ?>" placeholder="Escreva pelo menos uma palavra para realizar a busca... *" required="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                           <input type="submit" name="search" class="thm-btn thm-color" value="Buscar" />
                        </div>
                    </div>   
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

<script>
$(function(){
   $("#formBuscar").submit(function(){
         var search = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
         search = search.replace( " ", "+" );
         window.location = 'http://localhost/buscar/'+search;
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Imprimir os resultados da busca:

> **Resultado da busca**

```
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                 <?php

                 if(isset($_GET["search"]))  
                 {  
                      $condition = ''; 
                      $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);                     
                      foreach($query as $text)  
                      {  

                      $db->query ('
                                    SELECT noticia_title FROM noticia WHERE noticia_title LIKE "%'.$text.'%" or noticia_content LIKE "%'.$text.'%"
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT evento_id FROM eventos WHERE evento_nome LIKE "%'.$text.'%" or evento_content LIKE "%'.$text.'%" or evento_resumo LIKE "%'.$text.'%"
                                    UNION
                                    SELECT album_id FROM albuns WHERE album_name LIKE "%'.$text.'%" or album_descricao LIKE "%'.$text.'%"  
                        ')->fetchAll();

                        if ($db->rows == 0) {
                            echo "<div class=\"alert info\">Nenhum resultado foi encontrado na sua busca!</div>";
                        } else {
                        if ($db->rows == 1) {
                            echo "<p align=\"center\">Durante sua busca foi encontrado 1 resultado em nosso site.</p><br />";
                        }
                        if ($db->rows > 1) {
                            echo "<p align=\"center\">Durante sua busca foi encontrado $db->rows resultados em nosso site.</p><br />";

                        }
                                }       
                 }

                ?>
```

Lembrando: Se eu colocar apenas um palavra, vai funcionar normalmente. Agora se eu colocar duas palavras não aparece os resultados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme discutido nos comentários, o problema estava no arquivo `.htaccess` que estava assim:

```
RewriteRule ^buscar\/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?p=buscar&search=$1 [QSA]
```

A regex usada não estava casando outros caracteres passados no GET, mas apenas letras de `a` a `z`, números e hífen.

Mudando a regex para:

```
RewriteRule ^buscar\/([\w\W]+)/?$ index.php?p=buscar&search=$1 [QSA]
```

O problema foi resolvido pois agora passa a casar qualquer caractere passado no GET.